# OLS or logit when underlying continuous distribution exists, but only observe choices from a (discrete) set

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, least-squares, econometrics

Example: Suppose we are interested in the effects of time spent grocery shopping ($T$) on dollars spent at check out ($D$). However, we can only measure dollars in $\$5$ increments from $0$ to $100$ (i.e. all our measurements are from the set $\{0,5,10,\dots,95,100\}$

**Question** Which of a standard linear model (OLS) or discrete choice (logit, probit, etc) would be better to use on such data?

- What if instead of the discreteness being the result of our measurement, it was the result of subject choices ?(for example, what if the grocery store had a policy that an individual can only spent an increment of $5$)
- What if granularity is further decreased? (i.e. instead of observing increments of $\$5$, we observe increments of $\$20$)

Edit: I guess one concern might be with the error structure. Normality probably wouldn't be a great assumption here, and hence least squares may not work too well (granted we could maybe account for the error structure)

Comment: What if more than \$100 is spent? It's then recorded as \$100?

Comment: @dlnB Yes, if more that $100$ is spent then we record it as $100$. (I don't really want to get into censoring/truncation here... I'd rather just assume that the largest number is so large nobody will actually attain it, if that's alright. It may not be alright though)

Comment: Have you considered interval regression? What do you want to do with this model? Are you interested in the underlying continuous latent CEF?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I have not considered interval regression; I am not familiar with that technique. The goal in the example would indeed be interested in the underlying continuous CEF (i.e. specifically how $T$ affects the conditional expectation of $D$). Regarding the model... I don't wish to do anything with it. It is just an example. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of the limits/assumptions of the models (I feel like the books I've seen are lacking regarding *when* to use one approach vs another)

Comment: ake a look at the [tag:interval-censoring] tag and the keyword "interval regression." There are several good examples that should give you an idea of whether this is a good technique for you